# Managing objects with multiple contexts

Tags: php, oop, object

**Question:**

Is there a preferred design pattern for handling an object under different contexts? For example: if I need to GET a user from the database then that object **needs** to have an id and a privilege level. However, if I want to create a NEW user for registration then it **does not need** an id since this will be added in the database via auto_increment. A GUEST user does not need an id but should have a username of 'Guest'.

**Attempted Solutions**

Using a constructor seems to neglect context.

Creating new objects for registered_user, new_user, and guest_user seems wasteful.

Creating methods within the user object that can be used to initialize it in unique ways is tempting.

As of now I believe that I should create a **separate** factory that has functions such as create_guest($x), create_new_user($x, $y), create_registered_user($x, $y, $z)? This would allow the user object to have one purpose: hold a user (while still allowing it to have a constructor to establish a bare minimum requirement), and also have a user factory with the sole purpose of: initiating different types of users.

Please excuse any ignorance, just looking for the best design pattern for handling the same object in unique contexts.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    class user
    {

        private id;
        private username;
        private privilege;

        public function __construct()
        {
            some code...
        }

        public function is_admin()
        {
            some code...
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the provided class, you can always autoinitialize the value for `$this->id` to be 0 and use it to determine if this user is a guest. Main idea is that you will never have an id of 0 in your database (if you are using auto-increment for this column).

This can also be used to check if you are to update or create the record. A simple check on the id would reveal either 0 or another int. If it is 0, then it is either guest or it should be created. If it is greater than 0, it has already been created and it needs to be updated.

Generally, I prefer to pack the create and update into the user class itself by adding `load()`, `update()`, `create()` and `delete()` methods, where `load()` would accept an array/object which if passed will be used to load the data into the current context or if not supplied, the function will try to read the data from a different source (such as a DB).